# iPhone connecting XML with NSDictionary's key

Tags: iphone, xml, webserver

I have table with data taken from NSDictionary. For example Each row of table contains Currency Name and rate which are linked using NSDictionary. Now i want to take rate value from XML file over the network. 
I have made XML file and web server.

1. Is it possible?
2. How can i accomplish this.
3. Is it secure.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "take rate value from xml". Anything over network is not safe and hence there arised a need for cryptography and network  security. But thats a generic statement.

Comment: There are conversion rates for each currency. I have shown currency now i want to take conversion rates from XML file which is over the network. XML file is ready and webserver is ready. I just want to know how can i connect it with my rate conversion value. i used NSDictionary to link currency with rate.

Comment: Fetch the xml file parse the fields and recreate your dictionary. I cannot see what is the problem here. Do you want to know how to fetch the file from server, how to parse the xml, how to create the dictionary or how to edit a dictionary.

Comment: Yes i know i have to fetch the xml file and parse the fields. I want to know how to fetch, parse and link that with my dictionary values.

Comment: But since you have already created the dictionary you may want to change the values only which is easy to accomplish.

Comment: Yes. I was just wondering is it secure way to do the same task. like using xml with webserver and above process. Is it ok with commercial application. I know the data is not sensitive.

Comment: Its ok to do that, i added a answer with some logic to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you parse your xml file, use the reference to your dictionary and do the following:

Assuming the xml will have `<Currency> conversionrate </currency>` format. In your didendelement you can change the value of dictionary items as below:

```
    - (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{   
        [dictionary setValue:parseditem forKey:elementName];
}
```

parsedItem can be got from the method :

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
```

Here you have to take care that the element name has to be unique. You can also use attributes to do the same and add a if condition before adding it to the dictionary.

Comment: Cheers mate. i will implement your answer and will let you know. Thanks for your time.